# 'Callback' is a missing argument in call?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a Seperated Swift file for the call. this looks like this:

```
var DEVICEBUNDLE_API_ROOT = "https://apps-dev.profects.nl/profects-apps/current/web/app.php/api/v2/device"
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

init(action: NSString, data: NSString, callback: (success: Bool, data: NSDictionary) -> Void) {

    var body = "{\"action\":\"" + action + "\",\"data\":" + data + "}";

    var     request             =   NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: DEVICEBUNDLE_API_ROOT)!)
            request.HTTPMethod  =   "POST"
            request.HTTPBody    =   body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) // Use UTF-8

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {

        data, response, error -> Void in

        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Response: \(strData)")

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options : .MutableLeaves, error: nil) as? NSDictionary

        if let parsedJSON = json
        {
            if let status = parsedJSON["status"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let statusCode = status["code"] as? NSString
                {
                    if let responseData = parsedJSON["data"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        callback(success: statusCode == "201", data: responseData)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        callback(success: false, data: NSDictionary())
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

The call for the login looks like this:

```
var request = JSONRequest("registerDeviceId", "{\"email\":\"" + usernameField.text + "\",\"password\":\"" + passwordField.text + "\", \"UUID\":\"Tset124235346456457567\", \"OS\":\"Android\"}")
```

Now an error shows up saying 'Missing Argument for parameter 'callback' in call'

How can I fix this? I already tried adding an value "" at the end of the call.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the callback. This is the closure that will be called when the request has finished running.

```
let action = "registerDeviceId"
let data = ...whatever...
var request = JSONRequest(action: action, data: data, callback: { (success: Bool, data: NSDictionary) in 
    // Do something here with the success and data info that you got from the request
    return 
})
```

More information about [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)